# The right format for images in JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoding, decoding

I'm working on a project using Swift. For it, I have to create a JSON file, which should also contain images. Now, I've tried to add Images to Xcode's Assets catalog and then create from them a Base-64 encoded string (I would like their format in a JSON to be a String). I use this code for one image to create the string:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "restaurant")
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)

    let strBase64 = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
```

When I encode this to JSON, it works normal. The problem is, in the future I won't have a JSON file inside of my project. It will be requested from the server, so when I manually add the Base-64 encoded string of my image to the JSON (first, I type it on the console, then, just copy it to JSON), my JSON file becomes terribly long (more than 2000 lines for just one image). After looking at the structure of different JSON files, used in tutorials, I've noticed that for images, the authors of those files use url strings. So, I wonder, whether it is the default way to add images to JSON and I shouldn't try to copy the whole Base-64 encoded string of my image? This is the first time I'm trying to add an image to a JSON, so I would appreciate any suggestion and advice.

Comment: Absolutely use URLs, and fetch the images separately. Many advantages to that (including caching). Putting images into the JSON file is technically possible of course, but not really a good approach in most situations.

Comment: Don't do that. Do as Pekka said instead. ☝️

Comment: And if you need to post the image to the server don't use PNG. It will discard your image orientation and will be uncompressed data. You should always use JPEG representation data.

Comment: @Pekka웃,  thanks for your help. I have another question. In my project I'm using images with 3 scale factors (1x, 2x, 3x). So, for each of these images  and for each of their scale factors I should create a separate link, right?

Comment: @LeoDabus, thank you for mentioning that. My pictures are PNG. I'll change their format.

Comment: If they're different resources with different pixel sizes, then yeah, you'd want three separate links. Maybe as nested values: `"image_123": { "1x": "http://www...", "2x": "http://www....", "3x"....`

Comment: @Pekka웃, thanks for your explanation!